# Probability of a number being a bound for roots

Tags: probability, complex-numbers

.Consider the polynomial $p(z)=\sum_0^na_iz^k$ where $a_n=1$ and $a_k \sim N(0,1)$, $k=0,1,2,\dotsc,n-1.$
What is the probability that 2 will be a bound of the roots of the polynomial? How can we find the asymptotic probability for the same? I did a simulation for a polynomial of this type of degree 5 and I found im almost 91% of the cases, the roots lie within $|z| \leq 2$. However,I do not know how to go about it anlytically.I also wonder whether we can any good bounds for this probability ,if the exact computaion is theoretically intractable. Also, kindly reference the relevant literature, if any, about these kinds of problems about the random polynomials of the above-mentioned type. I would be  delighted and highly obliged for any help/hints/references.

**PS:- I must mention I posted this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439380/probability-of-a-number-being-a-bound-for-roots on MathOverflow and I was recommended to go through a couple of papers.However,I found that the papers deal with the asymptotic cases when n is very large and my problem is about a certain number  $c$being a bound for finite degree polynomials ,which requires to compute the probability that all roots lie within $|z| \leq c$ and I could not find any similar problem in the literature**